# Deriving left eigenvector from the left eigenvector of transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How would I find the left eigenvector of $A \cdot A^T$ if the left eigenvector of of $A^T \cdot A$ is $v$?

$\cdot$ is matrix product and ${}^T$ is transpose.

Comment: what is * and '? conjugate and transpose?

Comment: I'd guess $*$ is just matrix product, and $'$ is transpose

Comment: Yes, that is correct @ThomasAndrews